# Webcam not working on Ubuntu 16.04 with vmware

Tags: 16.04, vmware, webcam

I am having a hard time making my webcam work for Ubuntu on Vmware 10. The webcam drivers are working fine on the host machine (checked it while using the facebook video calling and google hangout), but doesn't seem to work on the guest Ubuntu machine. The webcam indicator light for my laptop is on when I use cheese, but no image or video is shown , just a black blank page.

[image: webcam not working on Ubuntu vmware.]

I also connected the Realtek_Integrated_Webcam_HD removable device from Vmware tools, still no luck.

Comment: Make sure _video capabilty_ is enabled in your VM settings

Comment: @George where can I find that setting?

Comment: which is __guest__ and which is __host__ ?

Comment: Windows 10 is the host and Ubuntu 16.04 is the guest

Comment: What is the _spec_ of your computer ?

Answer (score 5):

What worked for me was changing USB Compatibility from 2.0 to 3.0 in the VMWare settings for the linux guest.

Answer (score 3):

Change USB Compatibility to 1.1 in Virtual Machine Settings.

[image: VM Settings]

Comment: This does not work for me. However, as @mmcc73 recommended, using USB3.0 works fine for me.

Answer (score 2):

To get video capability in **VMWare**:

1. Make sure your **host** system has *video capabilities*.
2. Launch the vmware
3. In the vmware look at the bottom (note: not in the guest system) and select connect *to connect* to *host* video device

[image]

4. Note that **VMWare** will offer to disconnect the **video device** from the *host* please accept this. The video device should now work in the **guest os**.

**NOTE:** I tested this on -

- Windows guest in Ubuntu host, and should work in yours.
- Windows OS seems to **act greedily** when acquiring **hardware** on **host** and seems not to like to share (from my experience), so its possible that if your **guest** is Ubuntu then **it may not offer to disconnect from host** but if it does accept. That means the video device won't work on the *host* until you release it using the same steps as with connecting it.
- In *Virtualbox* this is done when the guest has been stopped, while in *VMWare* it does this with the **guest** running as in your case.

Hope this helps.

Comment: The video device is successfully connected to the guest , but when I start cheese, it shows me a blank screen (black screen ) and the webcam indicator is on. (The webcam is on but I cannot see any picture of myself)

Comment: please restart the guest and add it again.

Comment: sorry for the late reply, but it is still not working

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me with Windows 10 and Ubuntu 18.04 on an HP2570p was to start camera in Windows 10 and then connect the VM settings to the camera.  Note that "lsusb" did not list the camera device unless it was running in Windows 10 first. Also, the Windows camera app disconnects when the camera is running in Vmware and vice versa.  Manual disconnection of camera device from VM was necessary to resume operation in Windows 10 without rebooting ...

Answer (score 0):

1. Click on player on top of VMWARE
2. Click on "Removable Devices", then select your camera
3. Click on Connect(Disconnect from host)

Answer (score 0):

Tried in Ubuntu 20.04

Virtual Machine Settings -> Usb Controller -> Change the Usb Compatability under Connection to USB 3.1 or USB 1.1. This worked for me in cheese, kamoso, gucview and in opencv. Initially, it was by default set to USB 2.0.